# How to get at a C++ Container<T>'s T if no Container::value_type is provided?

Tags: c++, templates, containers, c++-concepts, template-templates

It's rather common that container templates contain a `value_type` typedef. This makes it easy to create other templated code, most recently concepts, which are able to extract the `T` if only having been given `Container` and not `Container<T>`.

However, not all containers (or other templated classes) define such a `value_type`, especially older ones.
Is it possible to get to the contained `T` even without it?

I know there are tricks like "if it is an iterator then `.begin()` should return a value of that type", but that does not help us to e.g. write a concept-requirement that checks whether a class's `.begin()` indeed follows the requirements that iterators have.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, without some prerequisite (a `value_type` type, a `begin()` method, the `T` type in first position of the template parameter list... or something else) that can be true for most but non all possible and conceivable containers. But... maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: If `typename std::iterator_traits<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(begin(c))>>::value_type;` is not valid, then `begin(c)` is technically not an iterator. At some point you need to draw a line with how far you're willing to go supporting things which are iterator-like but don't follow the modern technical requirements.

Comment: *what the value_type is* should be thought carefully. we can get `T` in `ClassTemplate<T, ...>`, get `value_type` from `std::iterator_traits<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(std::begin(cont))>>`, or get `std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(cont[0])>`, but which actually is what you want? if you just want to adapt the old container design, I think the one using `operator[]` is better.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I very much agree that whenever possible it is preferable to adapt the container class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that's similar to [Quimby's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66538757) but using partial template specialization instead:

```
template<typename...>
struct inner_type_impl;

template<template<typename...> typename C, typename T, typename...Args>
struct inner_type_impl<C<T,Args...>>
{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
using inner_type = typename inner_type_impl<T>::type;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3xP54h) that's borrowed from Quimby's solution.

Comment: Nice :) , I was too lazy to write the other option. I think this one turned out to be more readable also.

Comment: @Quimby Yeah, I find the specialization easier to read :) It's a matter of taste I suppose.

Comment: Very nice! I like both your and @Quimby's solution. I accepted this one  because I agree that it is slightly more readable :-).

Answer (score 3):

Class template specialization or template argument deduction can be used to implement this. Something like the following should work as long as the inner type is the first template argument:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Consider the first template argument to be the inner type.
template<template<typename,typename...>class C,typename T,typename...Args>
auto inner_type_impl(const C<T,Args...>* v)->T*{return nullptr;};

template<typename T>
using inner_type = std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(inner_type_impl((T*)nullptr))>;


template<typename T>
struct Container;

// Will still deduce T
template<typename T,typename...Extras>
struct ContainerExtraParams;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<int,inner_type<Container<int>>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int,inner_type<ContainerExtraParams<int,double,float>>>);
```

I use pointers to make the code valid in evaluated contexts too. Contrary to a possible solution involving `std::declval`.

Comment: Have I been out of things too long or has deduction always been capable of this? I was certain it would fail to deduce the class template in this case.
(I had to try this out in order to believe it!)

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde Most stuff in the example is C++11 and above but the template deduction itself works even in C++98. Not sure whether there were any changes to it.